# A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Array to string conversion Filename: mysql/mysql_driver.php Line Number: 552

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, code-injection, codeigniter-datamapper

Model :

```
function trans_gdc_add()
    {
$trans_gdc_gc_package[0] = $this->input->post('trans_gdc_gc_package');
$trans_gdc_gc_package1 = implode(",", $trans_gdc_gc_package[0]);
        $add=array(
                    'trans_gdc_no' => $this->input->post('trans_gdc_no'),
             'trans_gdc_to' => $this->input->post('trans_gdc_to'),
             'trans_gdc_vehicle_no' => $this->input->post('trans_gdc_vehicle_no'),
             'trans_gdc_vehicle_type' => $this->input->post('trans_gdc_vehicle_type'),
             'trans_gdc_vehicle_chas' => $this->input->post('trans_gdc_vehicle_chas'),
             'trans_gdc_vehicle_make' => $this->input->post('trans_gdc_vehicle_make'),
             'trans_gdc_vehicle_eng' => $this->input->post('trans_gdc_vehicle_eng'),
             'trans_gdc_vehicle_permit' => $this->input->post('trans_gdc_vehicle_permit'),
             'trans_gdc_vehicle_pol' => $this->input->post('trans_gdc_vehicle_pol'),
             'trans_gdc_vehicle_isby' => $this->input->post('trans_gdc_vehicle_isby'),
             '  trans_gdc_date' => $this->input->post(' trans_gdc_date'),
             'trans_gdc_from' => $this->input->post('trans_gdc_from'),
             'trans_gdc_driver_add' => $this->input->post('trans_gdc_driver_add'), 
            'trans_gdc_lic_no' => $this->input->post('trans_gdc_lic_no'),
             'trans_gdc_vehilce_owner_name' => $this->input->post('trans_gdc_vehilce_owner_name'),
             'trans_gdc_vehicle_owner_add' => $this->input->post('trans_gdc_vehicle_owner_add'),
             'trans_gdc_vehicle_owner_mob' => $this->input->post('trans_gdc_vehicle_owner_mob'),
               'trans_gdc_broker_name' => $this->input->post('trans_gdc_broker_name'), 
               'trans_gdc_broker_mob' => $this->input->post('trans_gdc_broker_mob'), 
               'trans_gdc_gc_no' => $this->input->post('trans_gdc_gc_no'), 
               'trans_gdc_gc_package' => $trans_gdc_gc_package1, 
               'trans_gdc_gc_cont' => $this->input->post('trans_gdc_gc_cont'), 
               'trans_gdc_gc_weight' => $this->input->post('trans_gdc_gc_weight'), 
               'trans_gdc_gc_freight' => $this->input->post('trans_gdc_gc_freight'), 
             'trans_gdc_gc_consignor' => $this->input->post('trans_gdc_gc_consignor'), 
             'trans_gdc_gc_consignee' => $this->input->post('trans_gdc_gc_consignee'), 
                                   'status' => '1'
        );
        return $this->db->insert('trans_gc_add',$add);


    }
```

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Array to string conversion
>
> Filename: mysql/mysql_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 552

Please help me to resolve this issue .

Comment: Which one is `Line Number: 552`?

Comment: If line 552 = return $this->db->insert('trans_gc_add',$add);, it looks like it wants a string in the $add parameter position, not the array. Is there documentation or a comment block for the db->insert method?

Comment: Error : Filename: mysql/mysql_driver.php

Line Number: 552

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
'  trans_gdc_date' => $this->input->post(' trans_gdc_date'),
```

space might be giving the problem, repla

```
'trans_gdc_date' => $this->input->post(' trans_gdc_date'),
```

Comment: your right but i think he should use new syntax and shouldn't use this type of array defining since he can't read and understand the error output telling him a clean syntax is importent for him to evolve!

Comment: @FrankfromDSPEED, yeah, but first error should be resolved and then he can go for syntax change

Comment: thks . I got the output.

Answer (score 0):

## You can't directly merge strings in arrays!

your trying to merge concatinate strings with arrays or lets say arrays with string thats not possible

## General Example

```
<?php
$stack = array("Orange", "Banane");
array_push($stack, "Apfel", "Himbeere");
print_r($stack);
?>
```

## for your code Example

```
      // array push tiggers a php array as stack!
        $add=array()
        array_push($add, 'trans_gdc_no', $this->input->post('trans_gdc_no'));
        array_push($add, 'trans_gdc_to', $this->input->post('trans_gdc_to'));
        print_r($add);
```